# Using fileinput to write to a file makes issue

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
for line in fileinput.FileInput("file.txt", inplace=1):
  if "success" in line:
    print(line)
```

When I use fileinput, the file 'file.txt' is not released. I could see the issue 'file.txt' still in use.
When I do the above function using normal file operation , no issue is shown

How to fix the issue with fileinput.

I used the below code snippet , but the issue is showing again . The file is not getting closed I guess

```
f = fileinput.input("file.txt", inplace=1)
    for line in f:
      if "success" in line:
      print(line)
    f.close()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Python 2.7, you have to explicitly call `close()` on the fileinput instance:

```
try:
  f = fileinput.input("file.txt", inplace=1)
    for line in f:
      if "success" in line:
        print line, end=""
else:
  f.close()
```

Since Python 3.2, the FileInput class can be used as a context manager. See the [fileinput documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/fileinput.html#fileinput.FileInput) for more information.

```
with fileinput.input(files=('file.txt'), inplace=1) as f:
  for line in f:
    if "success" in line:
      print(line)
```

Comment: Note that `fileinput` is meant to be used with multiple files; when iterating over lines in a single file, you might as well use `with file.open('file.txt') as f: ... f.readlines() ...`.

Comment: @Marjin - Yeah , I Know that. I need to understand what is the issue here. Why fileinput throws such an issue.

Comment: Thanks Marjin. The issue got resolved. My python version is 2.7 .

Comment: I updated my Python 2.7 answer (see above); you should be good once you explicitly close the `FileInput` instance.

Comment: Glad I could help. If my answer helped you, please use the check mark next to the answer to show others that your problem was solved.
Welcome to StackOverflow!

Comment: I tried with mentioned code , still close not working . I have updated the question. Please check

Comment: hmm ...  can you add the output of your code and how you check that "the file is in use"?

Comment: Any luck @Paddy?

Comment: Hi Marjin. It didnt work for me. I replaced fileinput with normal file operation  , open () . What you have mentioned is clear , we need to close the file using f.close() in python 2.7 .. But badluck for me.

Comment: OK, happy to hear you found another solution that works for you!